# npm install local subfolder eperm symlink

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

On a windows computer, I have a project, and am trying to install a local project in a subfolder:

```
main
 ├──node_modules
 ├──otherProject
 │   ├──node_modules
 │   ├──index.js
 │   └──package.json
 ├──package.json
 └──something.anything
```

> npm i ./otherProject -D

But i am getting

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ..\..\otherProject
npm ERR! dest C:\something\something\main\node_modules\@somescope\package
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '..\..\otherProject' -> 'C:\something\something\main\node_modules\@somescope\package'
```

There are extremely many similar problems, but all i found boil down to either `-g` and having no permissions for the global folder, or just having wrong permissions all around. I can `npm i <pkg-name> -g` just fine, i even have some global installs. This is supposed to be local, and require less permissions, not more. What is happening, and how can i fix it?

Edit:
Running the command from a shell with administrator permissions is not an acceptable solution. Explaining, that this would be required, is. In the latter case, i'd have to use a workaround, e.g. uploading to npm as a private package, and redownloading with a normal `npm i @scope/otherProject -D`. I don't see any reason, why a local link like this would require admin though.

Comment: it seems like you have limited access to your machine or npm installed incorrectly (it shouldn't require elevated rights when downloading dependencies unless global ones.) Check your npm installation and/or your permissions in the system.

Comment: As mentioned, i can type `npm i some-cli-package -g` and it will work. E.g. i still have `@vue/cli` installed globally from a previous project. I have dozens of packages installed in a dozen of projects. What fails is this local linking. There may be permissions issues, or a slightly faulty installation, i cannot rule that out. What confuses me, is that this is the command that should require the least permissions of them all, yet that's what fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating symlinks in windows needs administrator rights per default. Why this is the case is [not all too clear](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-you-have-to-be-an-admin-to-create-a-symlink-in-windows), but it's probably because of legacy reasons, which never got cleared out. Thanks microsoft.

In windows 10, since [roughly 2016](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/) you can enable developer mode, to allow symlinks for non-administrators.